# Maven repo in IntelliJ Idea not refreshing correctly

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gradle

I have downloaded IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 Community in 2 different places:

- Windows 7 PC
- Latest Ubuntu on a VM

I decided to give Gradle a try and so created new Gradle project in both places.
When I open `build.gradle` file and try to 'Add maven artifact dependency', initially my list is empty. So I go to IntelliJ->Settings->Maven->Repositories and update both local and remote repos. After that the behaviour is different depending on the Win/Ubuntu :

- On Windows 7, I can see my local repo with files on the actual hdd (under $home/.m2/repository). However in IntelliJ in the same menu as before ("Add maven artifact dependency") I can see only subset of the repo (only libraries starting with org.Jxxx - org.Wxxx)
- On Ubuntu there is no local repo created in my $home/.m2/repository , in fact there is not even $home/.m2 . In IntelliJ in the "Add maven..." I can see only libraries from a very narrow subset of all (org.Vxxx - org.Yxxx)

What is going on? I can't figure out what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it. Thanks :)

Comment: Sounds like you are using IntelliJ's Maven support, not its Gradle support. The local Maven repo is rarely used together with Gradle, which maintains its own dependency cache.

Comment: This still doesn't explain why I can't see any repos when I try to add maven artifact (or gradle dependency)

Comment: Perhaps you don't have any Maven repository declared in your Gradle build? It shouldn't be necessary to configure Maven repositories in IntelliJ when working with Gradle.

Comment: I do have a 'mavenCentral()' in build.gradle . And as I said, I am getting just a small subset of what I would expect (i.e. no groovy libraries when adding a dependency)